# excel vba: creating a range without referencing a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if I can save a generic range, without it having a sheet name attached to it?

Lets say that my program creates a sheet for every day of the week, and then makes headings for every sheet. I want to give it a few ranges, and it must merge and add different headings to those ranges in EVERY sheet. So the headings of every sheet looks the same.

I have the following range for example:

```
...
Set rowTwoHeadingKiloRange = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(2, 8)) 
Set rowTwoHeadingUnitRange = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(2, 14)) 
...
```

Now when I try to pass this range in a dictionary to every sheet that gets created, I find that I have undesired results as some of the headings gets created on sheets where they do not belong (And I think that is because when the range is created, it attaches to the active sheet at that moment - which may be different from time to time).

So now I basically have a function that looks something like this...

```
Public Function colmHeadingsAndSpacing(sheetName)
    With Worksheets(sheetName)
        ...
        Set rowTwoHeadingKiloRange = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(2, 8)) 
        Set rowTwoHeadingUnitRange = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(2, 14)) 
        ...
    End with
End Function
```

... and I run the function every time I create a sheet, with the name of the sheet that was just created given through. But this runs the function 7 times, when I use the same data (range) every time. Also I feel that it is not working properly as well (I still get strange reactions - ranges ending up in wrong sheets).

Second question, is there a way to find out on a range, what sheet is "attached" to the range. Something like: `msgbox rowTwoHeadingKiloRange.worksheets.name` which will give the result of `Sunday`

Comment: Anywhere you use `Range` or `Cells` add a full stop before. I.e. `.Range` and `.Cells`. This is how you attach those ranges and cells to the `With` statement

Comment: Also, whilst you're qualifying your references fully, also change `Worksheets(sheetName)` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)` to avoid any further strange behaviour in future

Comment: And on Q2, `msgbox rowTwoHeadingKiloRange.Parent.Name` should do the trick. Not the best design though

Comment: Off-topic; you can access ranges via their address.  I find this easier to read.  Example: both these statements return the same cells `Range(cells(2,4), cells(2, 8))` and `Range("$D$2:$H$2")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. To attach your `Range` and `Cell` to the `With` statement you need to use a full-stop `.` before the keyword. Like this:

```
Public Function colmHeadingsAndSpacing(sheetName)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        ...
        Set rowTwoHeadingKiloRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(2, 8)) 
        Set rowTwoHeadingUnitRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(2, 14)) 
        ...
    End with
End Function
```

This is good practice to qualify every range reference with it's attached worksheet. I went one step further included a workbook reference (`ThisWorkbook`). Now it's fully qualified.

For the second question -- try `MsgBox rowTwoHeadingKiloRange.Parent.Name` to get the name of the worksheet. It's usually better to start with the worksheet name rather than work back to it though.

Comment: Thanks CallumDA for all the help, I did it and it worked. When it comes to the second question, I only wanted to know for when I do "fault finding", and then work backwards as you say. I have no intention of using it to get data from, just to put you at ease   `:)`   Could you also just confirm for me if like my first block of code, there WILL be a sheet attached to the range, and you can not create a range without a sheet name attached?

Comment: @AlfaBravo if you just use the implicit `Range` call (unqualified) then VBA will interpret that as `Activesheet.Range` so it's whichever sheet was accessed last before the `Range` call. So yes there is always a worksheet attached to a range object but it's set automatically -- a recipe for disaster!

Answer (score 0):

A range is a reference of a (mostly rectangular) area on a sheet. So referring to a range without defining a sheet like `Set r = Range ("B2:F10")` is exactly the same as `Set r = Activeworkbook.Activesheet.Range ("B2:F10")`. So for more professional purposes VBA offers you the flexibility in the following way:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Add   ' open new xlsx file
Set ws = Activesheet OR 
Set ws = wb.Activesheet OR 
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
' do something else here and later when neither wb nor ws is active, you can
Set r = wb.ws.Range("B5:G22") OR 
Set r = ws.Range("B5:G22")
```

An addition: for producing a number of sheets of the same format, you may consider using templates either. Then you need to fill in only the differences programatically. Less programming, easier maintenance :)